# Most efficient way to load many files in spark in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

```
[Disclaimer: While this question is somewhat specific, I think it circles a very generic issue with Hadoop/Spark.]
```

I need to process a large dataset (~14TB) in Spark. Not doing aggregations, mostly filtering.  Given ~30k files (250 part files, per month for 10 years, each part being ~ 200MB), I would like to load them into a RDD/DataFrame and filter out items based on some arbitrary filters.

To make the listing of the files efficient (I'm on google dataproc/cloud storage, so the driver doing a wildcard glob was very serial and very slow), I precalculate an RDD of the file names, then load them into an RDD (I'm using avro, but file type shouldn't be relevant), e.g.

```
#returns an array of files to load
files = sc.textFile('/list/of/files/').collect()  

#load the files into a dataframe
documents = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').load(files)
```

When I do this, even on a 50-worker cluster, it seems that only one executor is doing the work of reading the files.  I've experimented with broadcasting the files list and read a dozen different approaches but I can't seem to crack the issue.

So, is there an efficient way to create a very large dataframe from multiple files?  How do I best take advantage of all the potential computing power when creating this RDD?

This approach works very well on smaller sets but, at this size, I see a large number of symptoms like long-running processes with no feedback.  Is there some treasure trove of knowledge -- besides @zero323 :-) -- on optimizing spark at this scale?

Comment: Have you considered caching and checkpointing ? How about tuning partition chunks ? This is very broad question to answer.

Comment: Yeah I realize it's very broad; that's what I was afraid of but I'm not sure where to go next.  Even general google pointers might helpful at this point to get me to find the right trigger words to research.  Trying not to be one of those "send me the codez pls" questions.

Comment: You need to be more specific about performance and configuration cluster wise and application wise. (I'm not saying it's not an interesting question thought)

Comment: The primary complexity to this process is that I need to do a row_number window over rows grouped by a specific key.  Imagine something like "For every Id, get me the first row, sorted descending by revision number."

The simplest way to do that is by putting everything into one large DataFrame, then applying the window.  I think a backup solution is to break it down into multiple passes, checkpoint the data, then do a final pass against all the intermediate outputs.  I'm just wondering if doing this in one shot is even a realistic approach.

Comment: Well that seems something completely different than just regular filtering. Why don't you break it to a top N row for each files, merge and top N again ? Complexity will drop by a log M factor.

Comment: But again, this is just an approach which may be far from optimal, but considering the information we have at hand it's hard to tell...

Comment: That seems like a great idea, actually.   That's worth exploring more.  The vast, vast majority of Ids, however, have only a single record, but it seems a conceptually solid approach.   I'll keep updating this and add any info here or in the answers for posterity's sake. There's really not a lot of readily available information re: this kind of scale.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116031/discussion-between-joshua-ewer-and-eliasah).

Comment: _it seems that only one executor is doing the work of reading the files._ - this is interesting. How do you observe that? It would suggest some data locality weirdness if it is true.

Comment: @zero323 threw a picture of my spark stats into that chat

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I want to do the same..

Answer (score 0):

Listing 30k files shouldn't be an issue for GCS - even if single GCS list request that lists up to 500 files at a time will take 1 second each, all 30k files will be listed in a minute or so. There could be some corner cases with some glob patterns that make it slow, but there were recent optimizations in GCS connector [globbing implementation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/releases/tag/v1.9.9) that could help.

That's why it should be good enough for you to just rely on default Spark API with globbing:

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("gs://<BUCKET>/path/to/files/")
```